# Normalize data range of "180 - 360" to the range "0 - 100" - jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a image that I am rotating, but it can only rotate between 180deg and 360deg. But I need the targetValue that is entered to be between 0 - 100.

So if you enter a targetValue of 20, it will then rotate the image 20% of the range 180deg - 360deg.

I have attached a snippet of the code that I have already -

Any help would be appreciated!

CODE -

```js
var targetValue = 100; //CAN ONLY BE BETWEEN 0 & 100

console.log(targetValue);

function targetChange(){
    $('#target').css('transform', 'rotate(' + targetValue + 'deg' + ')');
    console.log('hello');
}
targetChange();
```

```css
.target {
    position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="target" id="target" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/oarptf.png">
```

Comment: It's not 100% clear, there is a targetValue of 630. But you can only enter a percentage? `percentage / 100 * 360` ? Or do you want to `targetValue % 360` ? What is the input, and what is the expected output?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, sorry that was a typo. My mistake, the input value will be between 0 and 100. This will rotate the image between 180 & 360 degree's. So if 20 is entered, this will be 20% of the range 180-360.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is as simple as

- Take the input value (0-100)
- Find the proportion of 180 degrees
- Add that to 180 to give a value in the range 180-360

This is demonstrated below

```js
$('#input').on("change", function(){
    var val = +$(this).val();
    var rotAmount = 180 + ((val/100) * 180) 
    $('#output').val(rotAmount);
    $('#target').css('transform', 'rotate(' + rotAmount + 'deg' + ')');
});
```

```css
.target {
    position: relative;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter value between 0-100 <input id="input" type="number" min="0" max="100">
<br>
Rotation: <input type="text" id="output">
<hr>
<img class="target" id="target" src="http://i65.tinypic.com/oarptf.png">
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much Jamiec! Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
var targetValue = 100; //CAN ONLY BE BETWEEN 0 & 100

var normalizedValue = (targetValue / 100 * 180) + 180

console.log(targetValue);

function targetChange(){
    $('#target').css('transform', 'rotate(' + normalizedValue + 'deg' + ')');
    console.log('hello');
}
targetChange();
```

Comment: You're doing this the wrong way round. The input is from 0 to 100 and the output should be 180 to 360.

Comment: Thanks for the input bud, appreciate it.